# Pass a String into a String<Expression> for CriteriaBuilder.equal method using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a string: tmNumber, I need to pass tmNumber into the following method:

```
CriteriaBuilder.equal(Expression<String>.Expression<String>)
```

But I cannot figure out how to parse the tmNumber string into an Expression.

For simplicity I have removed a lot of code that isn't relevant to the problem. Just assume this is inside a method that has been passed a string called tmNumber

```
Expression<String> currentTm = trainingEntryRoot.get("tmnumber");
Expression<String> passedTmNumber = tmNumber; //tmNumber is a string I need to parse to Expression<String>, but how?
Predicate tmNumberPred = builder.equal(passedTmNumber, currentTm);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CriteriaBuilder also provides `CriteriaBuilder#equal(Expression<?>, java.lang.Object)` ([javadoc here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#equal(javax.persistence.criteria.Expression,%20java.lang.Object))) which could take the `Expression<String>` as the first parameter, and then your String `tmNumber` as the second argument.

This means what you have will almost work, with only slight modification:

```
Expression<String> currentTm = trainingEntryRoot.get("tmnumber");
Predicate tmNumberPred = builder.equal(currentTm, tmNumber);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am aware of the other version of the equal method. But: 
Expression<String> currentTm = trainingEntryRoot.get("tmnumber"); already works as is.

It's this part: Expression<String> passedTmNumber = tmNumber; that does not work. tmNumber being a string. But are you saying if I turn tmNumber into an object that it will work? How will it know which attribute of that new object to compare to?

Comment: @user2725919 I agree that currentTm is working fine. What I'm saying is that you do not need to parse tmNumber to an Expression<String>, CriteriaBuilder can do it as an Object/String. My sample code has just changed the order to satisfy the method contract.

Comment: Worked like a charm! I was skeptical that a String would compare to a string expression using the object version of the equal method. But it did. Thank you!